# Using RegExp to substring a string at the position of a special character

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a sting like this:  ABC5DEF/G or it might be ABC5DEF-15 or even just ABC5DEF, it could be shorter AB7F, or AB7FG/H.

I need to create a javascript variable that contains the substring only up to the '/' or the '-'. I would really like to use an array of values to break at. I thought maybe to try something like this.

```
...
var srcMark = array( '/', '-' );
var whereAt = new RegExp(srcMark.join('|')).test.str;
alert("whereAt= "+whereAt);
...
```

But this returns an error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: array

I suspect I'm defining my array incorrectly but trying a number of other things I've been no more successful.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Arrays can be created this way: `var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];`

Comment: I'm actually trying to get the value before the special character. So for example 'ABC5DEF' or 'AB7FG', dropping anything after the '/' or '-'. I figured I would just substring it out once I knew the location of the special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex with `String.split`.
It will look something like that:

```js
var result = ['ABC5DEF/G',
  'ABC5DEF-15',
  'ABC5DEF',
  'AB7F',
  'AB7FG/H'
].map((item) => item.split(/\W+/));

console.log(result);
```

That will create an Array with all the parts of the string, so each item[0] will contain the text till the `/` or `-` or nothing.

Comment: Many of these solutions worked, this is the one I settled on.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays aren't defined like that in JavaScript, the easiest way to define it would be with:

```
var srcMark = ['/','-'];
```

Additionally, `test` is a function so it must be called as such:

```
whereAt = new RegExp(srcMark.join('|')).test(str);
```

Note that `test` won't actually tell you where, as your variable suggests, it will return true or false. If you want to find where the character is, use String.prototype.search:

```
str.search(new RegExp(srcMark.join('|'));
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the split method:

```
var srcMark = Array.join(['-','/'],'|');  // "-|/" or
var regEx = new RegExp(srcMark,'g');      // /-|\//g
var substring = "222-22".split(regEx)[0]  // "222"
"ABC5DEF/G".split(regEx)[0]               // "ABC5DEF"
```

Answer (score 1):

From whatever i could understand from your question, using this RegExp `/[/-]/` in `split()` function will work.

**EDIT**:

For splitting the string at all special characters you can use `new RegExp(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/)` in `split()` function.

```js
var arr = "ABC5DEF/G";
var ans = arr.split(/[/-]/);
console.log(ans[0]);

arr = "ABC5DEF-15";
ans = arr.split(/[/-]/);
console.log(ans[0]);

// For all special characters

arr = "AB7FG/H";
ans = arr.split(new RegExp(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/));
console.log(ans[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the position of the special character (non-alpha-numeric) you can use a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp:) that matches any character that is not a word character from the basic Latin alphabet. Equivalent to [^A-Za-z0-9_], that is: **`\W`**

```js
    var pattern = /\W/;
    var text = 'ABC5DEF/G';
    var match = pattern.exec(text);
    var position = match.index;

    console.log('character: ', match[0]);
    console.log('position: ', position);
```